# Using Base Multiplication Operator in two child classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators

I'm attempting to program up a simple Matrix/Point class library, and I want to multiply two inherited classes using the base classes multiplication operator overload.

**EDIT 2**
Code Reverted back to original, for future travelers:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>


template <typename DataType, unsigned short NumberOfRows, unsigned short NumberOfColumns>
class GenericMatrix
{
public:

    GenericMatrix operator * (GenericMatrix const & rightHandSide)
    {
        //DO MATRIX MULTIPLICATION
        return GenericMatrix<DataType, NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns>();
    }   
};


template <typename DataType>
class RotationMatrix2D : public GenericMatrix<DataType, 2, 2>
{   
};

template <typename DataType>
class Point2D : public GenericMatrix<DataType, 1, 2>
{    
};

int main()
{
    RotationMatrix2D<double> rotMatrix;
    Point2D<double> point;

    point * rotMatrix; //Error here

    return 0;
}
```

This allows me to use the fact that a point is basically just a matrix.  However, I keep getting hit with a compiler error:

> Error C2679   binary '*': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'RotationMatrix2D' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

How do I get around this?

Comment: The template arguments don't match on the base class.

Comment: @AndyG What do you mean?

Comment: You should revert the code to as it stood in the original. The edit is just confusing.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe  Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that your operator is for a particular GenericMatrix template instance. To understand what is happening you can expand the operator inherited by Point2D like so:

```
GenericMatrix<double, 1, 2> 
GenericMatrix<double, 1, 2>::operator*(const GenericMatrix<double, 1, 2>& rhs)
```

Now, `RotationMatrix2D<double>` i.e. `GenericMatrix<double, 2, 2>` doesn't fit as an argument to rightHandSide, `GenericMatrix<double, 1, 2>` and `GenericMatrix<double, 2, 2>` are distinct unrelated types.

You can get around this by writing the operator as a templated function itself so the template can adapt to the different rhs type, i.e.

```
GenericMatrix<double, 1, 2>::operator*(const GenericMatrix<double, 2, 2>& rhs)
```

The following seems to work as intended:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>


template <typename DataType, int NumberOfRows, int NumberOfColumns>
class GenericMatrix
{
public:
    template<int N, int M>
    GenericMatrix operator * (const GenericMatrix<DataType, N, M> & rightHandSide)
    {
        //DO MATRIX MULTIPLICATION
        return GenericMatrix<DataType, NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns>();
    }   
};


template <typename DataType>
class RotationMatrix2D : public GenericMatrix<DataType, 2, 2>
{   
};

template <typename DataType>
class Point2D : public GenericMatrix<DataType, 1, 2>
{
};


int main()
{
    RotationMatrix2D<double> rotMatrix;
    Point2D<double> point;

    point * rotMatrix; //No compiler error here

    return 0;
}
```

I changed the numeric template parameters to int.

You probably also want to adjust the return type GenericMatrix< > template parameters to fit the returned matrix, but that is another question.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!  Thank you!  I changed the return type to auto fyi.